# Static files not loading on Amazon Bean Stalk for Django app

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-staticfiles, static-files

I know this question has been asked many times and I have tried all solutions mentioned on Stackoverflow but I didnt get mine to work.
So here is my question:

My code (on eb) is located under:

```
/var/app/current
```

and my folder structure is as follow:

```
.ebextensions
platform
platform_site
manage.py
settings.py
```

My dbmigrate.config file (under.ebextensions) has the following entries:

```
    option_settings:
      aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
        /static: static
container_commands:
  03_collect_static:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py collectstatic"
    leader_only: true
```

The static files were not loaded at run time.
So, when I looked at the log files, the log file (/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log) showed me that the static files were copied to this folder:

```
[INFO]  398 static files copied to '/var/app/staging/platform-site/settings/static'
```

However when I looked at the logs of NGNIX (/var/log/nginx/error.log) I saw that it was trying to load the static files from another folder:

```
    [error] 1717#1717: *11 open() "/var/app/current/static/platform/images/sensitive_data.png" failed
 (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.31.26.84, server: , request: "GET /static/platform/images/sensitive_data.png HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

This is strange.
Why is it copying to a "staging" folder and trying reading from the "current" folder? I have no idea why this is happening.

The funny thing is that I tried to search for this folder on my EB installation and it does not exist

```
var/app/staging/platform-site
```

Can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

My settings file had the following entry:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static/")
```

this was wrong. I changed it to the following and it worked.

STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

Comment: Glad you worked it out! This question has been repeated many times, you can delete this post.